# why is this recursive function not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried this in competitive programming but for some reason, this is not working. I am new to python programming.So, I am not understanding why this is not working. can someone help me out here?

```
def factorial(num):
    if num==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return num*factorial(num-1)

T=int(raw_input())
while T>0:
    n=int(raw_input())
    print factorial(n)
    T=T-1
```

where T is the no of test cases as can be usually seen on competitive programming. for T nos we have to find factorials. my previous question was not clear. now can anyone give me insights?? the error that i keep getting is nzec(non zero exit code) error .

Comment: Replace n with num and return num*factorial(num-1)

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Comment: There is so much wrong in this code.. What is `n`? why is the 2nd return not indented ?

Comment: my indentation is not broken in  real program.. i did that just for the shake of showing

Comment: and what is the point of showing code with a broken indentation ?

Comment: no point in broken indentation. please just look at the code that i have provided in the link. as i have already told this code was written just to show the structure. real strucuture is given in the link.

Comment: i will make it clear for you : this is not how to use Stack Overflow ! Edit your question and make it self contained.

Comment: okay noted. thank you

Comment: Now, why do you think it is not working? Do you get an error message? If yes, copy it here. Does the output you recieve is not what you expect? What do you expect then? BTW, you again have an indentation error.

Comment: after correcting the last indentation error that is of the function. i am getting this error "status:RE status detail:NZEC"

Comment: Your given code is working. The problem is somewhere else. `status:RE status detail:NZEC"` comes not from Python.

Comment: thank you so much Psytho and all other for helping. its running now. i am grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aditya* gave right solution in the comments!  Your code should be fixed as below:

```
def factorial(num):   
    if num==0:        
        return 1    
    else:        
       return num*factorial(num-1)
```

Comment: even this code is not working. i am using it in competitive programming.

Comment: https://code.hackerearth.com/f1104fD?key=5c5f506cdd6be4d2f0531d68831fcf8e

Comment: this code is working. the error is in the code you did not show.

Comment: Gilles Gouaillardet please look at the link that i have provided. this one. https://code.hackerearth.com/f1104fD?key=5c5f506cdd6be4d2f0531d68831fcf8e.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: No one will go to look at your code somewhere on unknown resource. You have to show your non-working code here.

Comment: FrankAk's code is working!

Comment: i have changed the question. i understand what was my mistake. it was my first question. so everyone please pardon me. i hope my question is undrstandable now.